# Libreria jquery no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, jquery

tengo este combobox anidado que funciona con php y mysql:

```js
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#bl3").change(function () {
    //$("#bl3 option:selected").each(function () {
           $("#bl3").each(function () {
            elegido2=$(this).val();
            $.post("caso2.php", { elegido2: elegido2 }, function(data){
            $("#cliente").html(data);
   
            });            
        });
   })
});


</script>
```

El problema que tengo es que, en mi maquina se ejecuta bien, pero en la maquina del cliente hala los datos pero también hala una casilla en blanco y no selecciona el dato en el segundo box de forma automática.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: checaste que en tu base de datos no haya ningún campo en blanco? escribe tu html

Comment: como hago para que no envie valores vacio a la tabla?

Comment: Con if() valida que los campos no vallan vacios

Comment: gracias ese era el problema

Answer (score 0):

debido a que ya se identifico el problema de validación de campos vacíos. Puedes hacerlo utilizando `if` para verificar que no valla en `null` asegurate tambien al momento de enviar de utilizar `trim()` para evitar el escape de espacios en blanco.